# No BlackBerry JRE is installed?

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I installed the blackberry plugin for Eclipse. When I click on new->project-> Blackberry->Blackberry Project

When I type project name it says "No BlackBerry JRE is installed. Please click "Configure JREs..." link to configure a BlackBerry JRE"

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Have you tried clicking 'configure JREs' ?

Comment: I'm having this problem too. I've tried clicking "Configure JREs..." but none of the JREs I have got installed makes the error message go away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed any component pack?

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp

If not, just add the update site http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java and download at least one component pack, and see if it finds any JRE

Comment: http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/java 
is latest one ... 
where to put this url in eclipse config files to avoid to grab the mouse ?